# Enabling Azure Diagnostics after 2.5 Upgrade

Tags: azure, diagnostics

I've been having trouble trying to get Azure diagnostics to work since upgrading to 2.5.  I went through the steps [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn186185.aspx#BK_Migration), but I get no data from my cloud service until I click on the role in the server explore, enable diagnostics, and fill out the form again.  Any ideas on how to fix this?  Since I have to do it each time I deploy (manually) it's a pain.

edit: It looks like this only is failing with powershell deploy, but deploy from VS is working correctly.  I'm guessing there are some new calls to make to enable diagnostics from powershell deploy.

Answer (score 1):

The steps at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kwill/archive/2014/12/02/windows-azure-diagnostics-upgrading-from-azure-sdk-2-4-to-azure-sdk-2-5.aspx should help, in particular the last section which shows how to do this via Powershell.